# Stop and disable Android system update on Motorola phones

Tags: updates, ota-update, motorola

My phone is a non-rooted Motorola Moto G4 Play (XT1607). It is getting old, there's no space left, and I don't want to update the Android operating system. By mistake, I clicked "Update" and it downloaded the update, but it is not yet installed.

[image]

Instead of proceeding to update, I want to delete it. I see a system app called `com.android.managedprovisioning`. Could this be it?

Comment: Have you tried anything that works for you?

Comment: @someuser I'm not rooted, don't know how, and don't wanna try to root

Comment: @someuser I don't have this phone anymore, it broke, but I have the same issue on my new Moto phone

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:
1-You can force close updater app:
Go to system-app-system updater then press "Force close"
2-uninstall updater app for the current user:
Note:You can restore updater app by doing "factory reset" to your phone?

```
pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.updater
```

**Note:**"com.android.updater" is package name of "updater" app in my phone,In your phone "updater" app may have another package name.You can find it using
[Package Name app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vjayraj.packagename).
I hope this help you

Comment: I see a system app called "com.android.managedprovisioning". Could this be it? My phone is a Motorola G Play, XT1607.

Comment: The package name should contain "updater" like this "com.android.updater" . 
   This code can be run from pc using adb:  "Adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.updater ",  but this code can be run from terminal emulator:  "pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.updater"

Comment: Where do i this? I'm not rooted and don't know how to.

Comment: This guide will help youto uninstall system apps:   https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I clicked the progress bar and a pop-up message showed and made it possible to cancel. In deleting the update, try this: File Explorer>Downloaded_rom>delete the update package there.

Answer (score 0):

I used PD NDM (package disabler) app, downloaded from its own website and requests support on how to disable update to version 9 android pie.
Disable the following :

com.sec.android.soagent

com.wssyncmldm

If com.wssyncmldm is not found, please disable com.wssnps

Answer (score 0):

On Moto Z2 Force, run this command from your PC when Android device is connected via USB in Photo transferring mode, USB debugging enabled.

`adb shell pm disable-user --user 0 com.motorola.ccc.ota`

You should not get anymore update popups.