# I accidentally started the download/install process for the Android 11 beta, can I cancel it?

Tags: updates, ota-update, android-beta-program

I have two Pixel phones on Android 10. Yesterday I joined the Android Beta program to get Android 11, with the intention to try Android 11 on one phone and keep the other on Android 10. I started the download/install process on one phone. Today, I wanted to check on the progress of the Android 11 update process, went to settings and saw that an update was available. Thinking that maybe it timed out and I just needed to try again, I chose to download/install the update.

Immediately after it started, I checked which phone I was looking at, and was horrified to find it was the *other* phone, the one I wanted to keep on Android 10. So I wanted to cancel the process on this phone, but there is **no cancel button**. Since the UI didn't provide the option, I thought I'd try killing the processes on the phone.

```
crosshatch:/ # ps -A | grep update                                                                                                         
u0_a64       10143   893 4987920  48108 SyS_epoll_wait      0 S com.google.android.configupdater
root         10773     1   44184   5808 SyS_epoll_wait      0 S update_engine
crosshatch:/ # kill -9 10143
```

This killed com.google.android.configupdater, but update_engine refused to die. Every time I tried killing update_engine, a new one would pop up.

When I went back to the system update screen, though, it mercifully indicated that the download was paused. BUT it only presented an option to Resume, NOT to cancel.
[image: Download/install screen with Resume button]

Even then, this reprieve was short lived, as it soon automatically chose to Resume, *without* receiving any indication from me that I wanted to do that.

I have now turned off the phone while trying to figure out how to keep it on Android 10.

I see that [in some cases](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/200971/stop-and-disable-android-system-update-on-motorola-phones), after the download is complete, the user will be given a final chance to decide whether to proceed. Is this true for the update to Android 11? And as the question in that link asks, can I choose to just delete the download instead? Or is there even some way to cancel the download in progress? I'm nervous about letting it complete and then maybe deciding for me that I want to proceed rather than selecting "Later".

**Update**
The other phone that I had intended to try Android 11 with, after the "download and install" process, did *not* give me a chance specify "Later" or "Cancel". So I can't just wait and cancel it, but may need to find some way to reset the "download and install" process while it is happening. Meanwhile I'm buying time by keeping the Android 10 phone off most of the time.

**Update 2**
I also did consider downgrading to Android 10 once Android 11 is installed, e.g., following [this guide](https://9to5google.com/2020/08/07/how-to-downgrade-from-android-11-to-android-10-on-google-pixel-video/), but it seems troublesome and potentially risky. Would much prefer some way to stop the present download/install of Android 11.

Comment: can you clear data of that package (configupdater)?

Comment: @alecxs Good idea, tried with `pm clear com.google.android.configupdater`, and it said success. When I go to system, it shows "Update available" (good, data was cleared, I guess?) but then I go to view it (which previously gave the choice to download/install), and it shows again that it is in the process of downloading the update. And the update_engine process is still there, and still auto restarts when killed.

Comment: please note bootloader version has downgrade protection which cannot by-passed in any way. you need to find the responsible package to clear. a factory reset will be more effective

Comment: @alecxs Thanks, good to know. Would prefer to cancel the download/install rather than let it complete and downgrade later.

Comment: guess the update is scheduled somewhere local, but consider they could have scheduled remotely too, maybe via bonded google account or via device serialno? in that case it might retry update even after factory reset (speculation)

Comment: be aware google doesn't offer any solution to unbrick unbootable device other than fastboot mode. therefore on google devices it is highly recommended to unlock bootloader (besides warranty period)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kept my android 10 phone off for some time. Finally, now that Android 11 is official, I found that the phone is still on Android 10, and now it only provides an option to upgrade to Android 11, but has not forcibly upgraded my phone.

So I guess one answer to my question would have been: Just wait till Android 11 comes out of beta, and then the download process for Android 11 beta would automatically stop.